# Why do I get the error "should not start with "$" or "_" which are reserved prefixes for Vue internals."?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, pinia

I am getting the following error when I am in my `Login` component:

```
[Vue warn]: setup() return property "$subscribe" should not start with "$" or "_" which are reserved prefixes for Vue internals. 
  at <Login backend="http://localhost:1337" onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView backend="http://localhost:1337" > 
  at <App>
```

I get multiple similar errors from other variables in `runtime-core.esm-bundler.js`.

Everything was working previously and I believe no changes were made to the code. I think it is coming from my `setup()` in the login page which returns Pinia:

```
    setup() { 
      const userStore = useUserStore()

      return userStore
    },
```

I am not sure how to solve this issue, since the error seems to come from a bundle!

**EDIT:** I have edited my `setup()` as per Estus Flask's suggestion. I now receive an error when trying to pass the credentials of the user to the server.

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler 
  at <Login backend="http://localhost:1337" onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< 
Proxy { <target>: {…}, <handler>: {…} }
 > > 
  at <RouterView backend="http://localhost:1337" > 
  at <App>
```

When I use hardcoded credentials it works, but when I try to use the same credentials through the form the error appears.

Here is the form:

```
<form @submit="login" class="login-form">
        <label class="input-label">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" required class="input" v-model="credentials.username" @input="updateCredentials" />
  
        <label class="input-label">Password</label>
        <input type="password" required class="input" v-model="credentials.password" @input="updateCredentials" />
  
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="button loginButton" @click="login"/>
        <input type="button" value="Register" class="button registerButton" @click="register" />
      </form>
```

Comment: userStore object is destructured and builtin pinia properties are accessed. Should be `{ userStore }`, or use storeToRefs to extract the items you need

Comment: Thank you, it got rid of the initial errors in setup()! Now, they appear when I try to connect to the server when the user's credentials are used. I hardcoded the credentials of the user and this worked and everything went through.

Could it be the way I access the credentials?

Comment: form @submit="login" class="login-form">
        <label class="input-label">Användarnamn</label>
        <input type="text" required class="input" v-model="credentials.username" @input="updateCredentials" />
  
        <label class="input-label">Lösenord</label>
        <input type="password" required class="input" v-model="credentials.password" @input="updateCredentials" />
  
        <input type="submit" value="Logga in" class="button loginButton" @click="login"/>
        <input type="button" value="Registrera" class="button registerButton" @click="register" />
      </form>

Comment: Which errors? Please, be specific, and update the question with code instead. It lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , there are no updateCredentials, etc

Comment: My apologies, I have now edited my original question with additional information.

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce. There's likely an error in login, currently only you can debug it. `v-model="credentials.username" @input="updateCredentials"` - this is likely wrong, generally you don't need to use v-model with events, they are mutually exclusive

Comment: For reasons completely unknown I have fixed the error by changing `type="text"` to `type="email"` for my username input. I have no idea why this would occur since I do not check for type. I am, however, very happy it is working!